# Restrict prefix in S3 bucket per Lambda Invocation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda which writes to an S3 bucket. On each invocation of the Lambda, the function writes to a particular prefix within the bucket (e.g. by timestamp). I want to guarantee a level of security by preventing the Lambda from overwriting other folders created from previous executions.

Is there a way to set access permissions per invocation? I don't think I can use just a policy since those are static. One idea is to change the permissions beforehand but this seems like bad practice. Moreover, this probably won't work if the Lambda runs concurrently. Any ideas?

Comment: You could write a 2nd Lambda function which is scheduled to run daily, say early am, and whose job it is is to modify the IAM role associated with the original S3-writing Lambda function. It would update the associated IAM policy and modify the allowed resource ARN e.g. to `arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/YYYYMMDD/*` where YYYYMMDD is today's date.

Comment: @jarmod This would work, but I also need to support concurrent executions of the same Lambda. Each invocation needs to be restricted to its own directory. Using the example from above, the Lambda is restricted to YYYYMMDD-Invocation#/*. Would the same approach work? Could there be race conditions or any slowdown?

Comment: I don't think there's any off the shelf way to accomplish this.  You could put the bulk of your logic in a Lambda layer, and deploy two Lambdas that both reference the same layer, along with different access restrictions.

Comment: I'd suggest building trust into the code rather than relying on permission restrictions. Write your code such that it checks for the existence of objects in S3 before creating them to make sure it doesn't overwrite existing data.

Comment: @AnonCoward So a Lambda is created on the fly with the desired prefix. Only then is it invoked. I will try this.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Technically the Lambda reads in user submitted code which is then executed. Granted this is a personal project, so the only malicious user is myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading this question in the context of your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73372448/pythonic-and-secure-way-of-running-scripts-in-aws-lambda) about running other people's code in the Lambda function, I would recommend:

- Dynamically create the Lambda function and **only use it once** (avoids security issues)
- **Do not assign an IAM Role** to the Lambda function
- Instead, **create temporary credentials** when dynamically creating the Lambda function

  - Create the credentials using [AssumeRole](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html) but pass a **policy** that limits the permissions down to only the bucket and path they are permitted to access
  - Pass these temporary credentials as Environment Variables
  - Tell the users that they'll need to grab the credentials from the Environment Variables, and show them some sample code

This way, you are fully in control of the permissions assigned to each dynamically-created Lambda function.

Comment: If I need to invoke the Lambda multiple times, would I still be able use the temporary credential approach?

Comment: Given that the code is coming from the user, you would need to keep the specific Lambda function for that specific user and that specific code. You'd also need some sort of 'cleanup' mechanism to remove the Lambda functions after some time. This can become overly complex, so it would be better to use each dynamic Lambda function once. But, by all means experiment!

Comment: And when you say creating temporary permissions , you in addition mean passing the ARN returned by AssumeRole for lambda creation?

Comment: I am suggesting that you should _not_ assign an IAM Role to the Lambda function because the permissions would be too big. Instead, call AssumeRole yourself while passing a policy that will **further restrict permissions** to only what that user and function should be allowed to access.

Comment: The boto3 client requires an ARN to be passed on Lambda creation, so I would need to somehow pass this as an ARN even though its not actually a role but really some type of session policy. So in the case of AssumeRole, AssumeRole will grant me credentials for permissions restricting bucket prefixes and will return an ARN under "AssumedRoleUser." I believe I need this or something of this sort or otherwise create_function will fail. Is this the case?

Comment: IAM Roles are not 'passed' to an AWS Lambda function when the function is invoked. They are associated with the function (or not) as part of the function configuration. If you are referring to the `Invoke()` command, the only ARN you pass is to identify the function to be invoked.

Comment: No, I am referring to create_function when the Lambda is initially configured and created. This is for step 1 of the strategy above.

Comment: Oh! Just point it to an IAM Role with no permissions.

Comment: Thanks. So far I can create a lambda that starts of with a blank role but has credentials to a temporary role with access to all the bucket. I am still having trouble restricting access only to the prefix desired. My original mental model for solving this was to have the underlying role associated with AssumeRole to have access to all the bucket. On a call to AssumeRole, the creator lambda would attach an inline policy using the 'Policy' parameter which would undo access to all the bucket and grant permissions to the desired prefix.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247410/discussion-between-ian-l-and-john-rotenstein).