# Strategies to run user-submitted code on AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I'm building an application that can run user-submitted python code. I'm considering the following approaches:

1. Spinning up a new AWS lambda function for each user's request to run the submitted code in it. Delete the lambda function afterwards. I'm aware of AWS lambda's time limit - so this would be used to run only small functions.
2. Spinning up a new EC2 machine to run a user's code. One instance per user. Keep the instance running while the user is still interacting with my application. Kill the instance after the user is done.
3. Same as the 2nd approach but also spin up a docker container inside the EC2 instance to add an additional layer of isolation (is this necessary?)

Are there any security vulnerabilities I need to be aware of? Will the user be able to do anything if they gain access to environment variables in their own lambda function/ec2 machine? Are there any better solutions?

Comment: You might be interested in this discussion on the same topic: [Restrict prefix in S3 bucket per Lambda Invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73377238/174777) -- have a read of the comments and you'll see they were seeking to do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Any code which you run on AWS Lambda will have the capabilities of the associated function. Be very careful what you supply.

Even logging and metrics access can be manipulated to incur additional costs.